# iMacros +JavaScript (using Char function)

Tags: javascript, char, imacros, fromcharcode

I'm trying to program a short script that emulates human behavior, which includes pressing the keyboard END key. Not sure how I can make it work.

Using `iimPlayCode("String.fromCharCode(35)");` doesn't work as this is a STRING function and I need it to be a key object or command.

In other words, is it possible (by means of JS code) to make the machine "press" the key itself when I need it in a certain moment?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```
iimPlayCode("EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35");
```